# Angular2-MQTT only over Websocket?

Tags: angular, mqtt

So I'm using the [Angular-MQTT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-mqtt) library and if I want to connect on a none-websocket Broker, I get this error-message:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://iot.eclipse.org:1883/mqtt' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

So is it somehow possible to connect on a none-websockets Brokers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The npm page says it's using the [Paho JavaScript](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) client, that client only supports connecting to brokers that support MQTT over WebSockets